# Excel multiple drop down list from single Defined name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data sheet with defined name with list of contents ex Defined name " Cars"

```
**Cars**
Honda
Nissan
Ford
```

Honda, Nissan, Ford have defined name of "Cars" as mentioned above. I have other defined names and list in my data as honda, nissan, and ford and have a drop downs prepared for the list that is dependent on the selection of the above. ex source:

```
=INDIRECT($B4)
```

so if you would choose honda for example a list under would yield 
    new
    used
    certified

But in another cell in the file i want another drop down list dependent on the first selection of cars to yield different set of questions ex: honda is selected, 2nd drop down would read

```
orange
green
yellow
```

Currently I'm not aware to have a 2nd dependent drop down doing this because to my knowledge the defined name has to be the same as in this case 'Honda', and cannot be a repeat name. All of my other dependent questions and drop downs, depend on having 'honda' selected.

Is there a work around or different formula i should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are always crazy formulas you can use! Here's a sheet that should show you everything you need to know... [image: SampleSheet]

The lookup table is on the top left. Next to every possible make, it defines (in plain text, *not in formulas* the cells to look at for that field. The top middle and the top right are tables containing the lists of dependent dropdown items.

So if I select "Honda" in the first dropdown, the second dropdown is filled with values from F2:F3 and the third dropdown is filled with values from J2:J4.

The data validation formulas are written in plain text next to each dropdown. They should be what you would write in the data validation forms. The top-level dropdown is still just a simple reference to the top-level items ("Make"). The dependent dropdowns are of the following form:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP([TOP-LEVEL-DROPDOWN-CELL],[DEPENDENT-REFERENCE-TABLE],[COLUMN],FALSE))
```

This will first find the reference like F2:F3 in the table via `VLOOKUP`, then will pass it to `INDIRECT` in order to make it a usable reference for data validation. No named ranges required, though if you wanted to use named ranges you could put them in the reference columns (e.g. replace the F2:F3 with "HondaDescriptions" then define that name to be the range F2:F3).